# How to view a fixed number of points on timechart of achartengine?

Tags: achartengine

For LineChart I used

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer=new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
 mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
  mRenderer.setXAxisMax(30);
```

When I use the same for TimeChart, my graph disappears, only the layout is visible. Is there any other way I can display a fixed number or points on my graph?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the X axis range for a time chart is much wider, given by the values returned from the `getTime()` method in `Date`.